# Can min() be modified to select the minumum value that is above 0

Tags: sql, min

I have an sql table and I want to select the min value excluding 0. Any idea how can I do so?

Comment: A where condition can solve that instead of trying to fix the MIN function

Comment: could you please provide provide some sample data and desired output. For now it looks like you can use SELECT MIN(COLUMN)FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE COLUMN <>0

Comment: `minumum value that is above 0` and `min value excluding 0` are very different things. What is it that you want?

Comment: In standard SQL you could use `min(the_column) filter (where the_column > 0)`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the following request

```
SELECT min(field)
FROM table
WHERE field != 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I I already tried adding a where condition but it didn't work. Here's the code I've wrote:
declare @min int = (select min(note) from dbo.notation where min(note) != 0);
print cast(@min as varchar);
I also tried a > 0 condition.

Comment: I've tried with SQlite and it works, which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Azure Data Studio

Comment: Ouch, can't help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The query you've provided (shown below) is not going to work since you are using aggregate function (min) in the where clause, which is not allowed.

```
declare @min int = (select min(note) from dbo.notation **where min(note) != 0)**; print cast(@min as varchar);
```

I think  Maxime Challon's query will give you the expected result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).